# mysql trigger data from a many to many relation

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.6, ddl-trigger

I am new to triggers, so I want to know how I could select attributes from 3 different tables to insert them into a new table.

I have 3 tables with a many to many relationship:

- table `users` wich has `id_user` and `name_user`
- table `toys` which has `id_toy` and `name_toy`
- table `user_has_toy` which has both of the id's `user_id` and `toy_id`, this table is the relation many to many between `users` and `toys`.

I want to insert `name` and `toy` in a new table using a trigger.

```
create trigger ai_usertoy 
after insert on users
select (name_user,name_toy)
new.name_user,
toys.name_toy
from toys
```

The problem is that i dont know how to handle this third table ids in the trigger to know which `id_user` correspond to a `id_toy`.

Comment: what do you want the trigger to do?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a `TRIGGER`, use a Stored Procedure.

Normally a Trigger acts on a single table, in response to an `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` on that one table.  To build a many:many relation, you need "names" from two different tables.  That can't happen with a single insert/etc.

The Stored Procedure would take the two names you mentioned and it would do two IODKUs (search for `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ..`) plus a third `INSERT` into the many:many relationship table.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need in a trigger. You must simply execute 3 queries:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO users (name_user) VALUES ('User Name');
INSERT IGNORE INTO toys (name_toy) VALUES ('Toy Name');
INSERT INTO user_has_toy (user_id, toy_id)
    SELECT u.id_user, t.id_toy
    FROM users, toys
    WHERE u.name_user = 'User Name'
      AND t.name_toy = 'Toy Name';
```

The field `name_user` in the table `users` must be unique. In such case the user will be inserted if it is a new one, and not inserted if it already exists. But after 1st query it will exist in any case (of course if some another problem not occured).

And all the same with toy.

All 3 queries can be executed as one query if your connector allows milti-quering. Otherwise place them to a stored procedure.